SD card suddenly became very slow
I have a SanDisk Extreme Pro UHS-I V30 128GB microSDXC card, which I use with a microSD to SD adapter in my mirrorless camera.
I used to be able to download my photos and videos via the builtin SD card slot on my HP EliteBook 8470p to the builtin SSD at around 35MB/s continuous transfer rate, but now for some reason it only does 1 MB/s - none of my system specs have changed, but I did upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.
In dmesg the following appears endlessly while copying:
[418684.451297] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 210 at drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c:1180 sdhci_prepare_data.isra.0+0x370/0x630 [sdhci]
[418684.451311] Modules linked in: exfat mmc_block snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib snd_ump mc uas usb_storage snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables qrtr amdgpu amdxcp drm_exec gpu_sched drm_buddy input_leds joydev mac_hid intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_ctl_led ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic kvm snd_hda_intel irqbypass snd_intel_dspcfg crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel mei_hdcp sha256_ssse3 snd_intel_sdw_acpi mei_pxp sha1_ssse3 radeon snd_hda_codec aesni_intel crypto_simd snd_hda_core drm_suballoc_helper hp_wmi drm_ttm_helper cryptd snd_hwdep sparse_keymap wmi_bmof platform_profile snd_pcm ttm rapl iwlwifi intel_cstate snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event binfmt_misc snd_rawmidi snd_seq
[418684.451356]  snd_seq_device cfg80211 snd_timer drm_display_helper cec snd mei_me nls_iso8859_1 rc_core i2c_algo_bit mei lpc_ich soundcore tpm_infineon hp_accel lis3lv02d wireless_hotkey serio_raw sch_fq_codel overlay iptable_filter ip6table_filter ip6_tables br_netfilter bridge stp llc arp_tables msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq libcrc32c hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul sdhci_pci psmouse xhci_pci e1000e ahci cqhci xhci_pci_renesas sdhci libahci video wmi
[418684.451389] CPU: 5 PID: 210 Comm: irq/18-mmc0 Tainted: P        W  OE      6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu
[418684.451391] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP EliteBook 8470p/179B, BIOS 68ICF Ver. F.74 04/11/2019
[418684.451392] RIP: 0010:sdhci_prepare_data.isra.0+0x370/0x630 [sdhci]
[418684.451400] Code: fe ff ff 45 89 ee 41 81 e6 80 00 00 00 41 81 e5 00 01 00 00 75 70 45 85 f6 0f 84 8b fd ff ff 41 be 03 00 00 00 e9 3a fd ff ff <0f> 0b 83 a3 f4 02 00 00 fb e9 8d fd ff ff 48 8b 40 08 48 85 c0 0f
[418684.451401] RSP: 0000:ffffb2780132bd08 EFLAGS: 00010086
[418684.451403] RAX: 00000000ffffffe4 RBX: ffff8e7f03528640 RCX: 0000000000000000
[418684.451405] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[418684.451406] RBP: ffffb2780132bd30 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[418684.451407] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8e81761ade48
[418684.451408] R13: 0000000000000003 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8e7f03528640
[418684.451409] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8e822dc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[418684.451411] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[418684.451412] CR2: 00006161296a6000 CR3: 00000001096de001 CR4: 00000000001706f0
[418684.451414] Call Trace:
[418684.451415]  <TASK>
[418684.451418]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[418684.451421]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[418684.451426]  ? sdhci_prepare_data.isra.0+0x370/0x630 [sdhci]
[418684.451433]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[418684.451436]  ? handle_bug+0x51/0xa0
[418684.451439]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[418684.451441]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[418684.451444]  ? sdhci_prepare_data.isra.0+0x370/0x630 [sdhci]
[418684.451450]  ? sdhci_prepare_data.isra.0+0x2e4/0x630 [sdhci]
[418684.451457]  sdhci_send_command+0x31f/0x390 [sdhci]
[418684.451464]  sdhci_finish_command+0x206/0x2f0 [sdhci]
[418684.451471]  sdhci_cmd_irq+0x25a/0x2a0 [sdhci]
[418684.451477]  sdhci_irq+0x381/0x590 [sdhci]
[418684.451483]  ? __schedule+0x284/0x6b0
[418684.451487]  ? __pfx_irq_forced_thread_fn+0x10/0x10
[418684.451489]  irq_forced_thread_fn+0x35/0x90
[418684.451492]  irq_thread+0xfb/0x1c0
[418684.451494]  ? __pfx_irq_thread_dtor+0x10/0x10
[418684.451496]  ? __pfx_irq_thread+0x10/0x10
[418684.451498]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[418684.451500]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[418684.451502]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[418684.451505]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[418684.451506]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[418684.451510]  </TASK>
[418684.451511] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---

Any ideas how to fix this (because it is unacceptable to have it take more than a whole day to copy the whole card, as opposed to one hour before)
